# Showing FAB only after complete load

Tags: android, webview

I created a basic webview app...
It has a Progress Bar which hides after the page has loaded completely,
On top of it I created a FAB without library i.e. by using ImageButton...
I want to Show the FAB only after page load & not everytime (e.g Like when Offline)
how to achieve that?
here's the Code pic...
[image: WebView Code]

Answer (score 0):

Implement WebViewClient and extend onPageFinished() as follows,

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
     // do your stuff here
  fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}});
```

Comment: as I am using ImageButton, so instead of fab.setVisibility I should be using ImageButton.setVisibility right?

Comment: gettin Errors... btw I updated the Que. with Code... where should I put your provided Code? :)

Comment: Please override the onPageFinished() method in your myWebClient class.or just copy paste   @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
      fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

Comment: Note: try to use java naming conventions 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java

Comment: throws error 'Unknown Method super.onPageFinished' :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113717/discussion-between-darwin-and-user6330086).

Comment: how to hide FAB at initial launch?
I added fab.setVisibility on PageFinished but it still visible before page load...

Comment: try adding android:visibility="gone" to FAB in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution to hide the progress dialog when page loaded.

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            private int webViewPreviousState;
            private final int PAGE_STARTED = 0x1;
            private final int PAGE_REDIRECTED = 0x2;



            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                webViewPreviousState = PAGE_STARTED;
                if (dialog == null || !dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", getString(R.string.dialog_loading), true, true,
                            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                    // relax
                                }
                            });
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (webViewPreviousState == PAGE_STARTED) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    dialog = null;
                }

            }
        });
    }
```